# CodeGolf - Barry the messy developer #2

Tags: code-golf, string, number

> This is a follow-up of
>   [CodeGolf - Ignore the noise #1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50381/quickgolf-ignore-the-noise-1)
>   the only problem being that Barry has made things even worse for us. Lets see what happened

#### Update

I've added code to create random input and expected output because I'm not that good at explaining what I want, and I guess that sometimes words are more misleading than code (isn't that always?)

#### Description

Another method in *Dumb Corp*'s API gives us the current price a provider is giving us for an item, the optimal price we would be making maximum sales with and the tendency of that price compared to previous prices as a string `UP` or `DOWN`. We need to decide if we should remove the item from the shop or wait.

#### Input

```
80,90,UP
150,100,DOWN
65,65,UP
1618,1618,DOWN
840,1200,DOWN
54,12,UP
30,1,UP
```

For a huge input sample demo with expected output, put the following code (js) in your browsers console and it should output valid random input for testing.

```
var output = "";
var result = "";

for(i=10;i--;){
  var currentPrice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
  var optimalPrice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
  var tendency = Math.round(Math.random())?"UP":"DOWN";
  var tresult = "WAIT\n";

  if((currentPrice > optimalPrice && tendency == "UP") ||
     (currentPrice < optimalPrice && tendency == "DOWN")){
       tresult = "STOP\n";
     }

  output +=currentPrice+","+optimalPrice+","+tendency+"\n";
  result +=tresult;
}
console.log(output);
console.log(result);
```

As always we will have a variable `G` as our input, however if your language makes it easier for you to simply read the input, that's also fine. The format is constant, and follow the format `int,int,string`

#### Desired Output

You're the brains of this operation, Barry should be doing this calculation on the server, but we can't count on him as you should know. You need to output `WAIT` if the tendency is towards the optimal price, or `STOP` if the tendency is towards loses.

In other words, with the `80,90,UP` as input, we know that there is a product with current price of 80 and optimal price of 90 with a tendency to rise up, so we should `WAIT`. On the other hand, `840,1200,DOWN` means the product price is going down and our optimal price is higher, so we should stop losses by outputting `STOP`.

If the two prices are identical, output `WAIT` regardless of the tendency.

Each product in a new line, single word per line:

```
WAIT
WAIT
WAIT
WAIT
STOP
STOP
STOP
```

Please, when possible, provide a way of verifying that your code is working since we can't all know just by looking at the syntax. As always, **use as few characters as possible** and remember that you're not competing against other languages necessarily, your competing against languages with similar syntax

Comment: Your test data isn't terribly useful without expected results.

Comment: @NotthatCharles: I'm pretty sure the block in the Desired Output section of the post is the expected result of the test data in the Input section.

Comment: I meant the "huge input sample"

Comment: I realice now that it wasn't really helpful, updated the code to provide expected output.

Comment: Does the program have to work for several lines of input or just for one at a time?

Comment: Please, several lines

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer scoring in characters? The default around here is bytes (in an *existing* encoding of the participant's choice). With characters you just get people compressing their code by encoding it in Unicode characters and things like that. (Whatever your choice, don't change it for this challenge now, but you might want to keep it in mind for future challenges.)

Comment: To be fair, this is my third game and I wasn't aware of the difference between doing it in bytes or characters, although now that you mention it it makes total sense, sorry for that. Are all languages susceptible to being encoded to reduce character count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 27 characters

```
"㫅㍸ꕆ敟鸢Ꝓ約䢫솓儓隆뻨"2G#b128b:c~
```

This is just an encoded version of the following code (in order to make use of the scoring by characters):

```
r{',/:~3<)(f*~<"STOP""WAIT"?Nr}h
```

[Run all test cases here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7B'%2C%2F%3A~3%3C)(f*~%3C%22STOP%22%22WAIT%22%3FNr%7Dh&input=80%2C90%2CUP%0A150%2C100%2CDOWN%0A65%2C65%2CUP%0A1618%2C1618%2CDOWN%0A840%2C1200%2CDOWN%0A54%2C12%2CUP%0A30%2C1%2CUP)

There might be a way to shorten this by encoding `STOP` and `WAIT`, but I'm quite happy with the rest.

### Explanation

The code is surrounded by a loop which reads on line at a time, processes it, then pushes a newline, and reads the next line... The loop terminates once `r` returns an empty string (i.e. after all lines have been processed). That's this bit:

```
r{ ... Nr}h
```

As for processing each line, I'm making use of the fact that upper case letters are variables in CJam, so I can eval some of the input.

```
',/:~3<)(f*~<"STOP""WAIT"?
',/                        e# Split the input on commas.
   :~                      e# Eval each of the three resulting strings. The first two
                           e# will yield the prices, the third will dump a bunch of
                           e# values corresponding to the variables DNOPUW in the array.
     3<                    e# Truncate to three elements, so we only get the prices and
                           e# the values corresponding to U (0) and D (13).
       )(                  e# Slices off that variable value and decrement it, to get
                           e# something negative for UP and positive for DOWN.
         f*                e# Multiply both numbers by that value. So if we had UP then
                           e# both numbers will be negative now, otherwise they'll just
                           e# be scaled without affecting their relative size.
           ~<              e# Unwrap the array and check which element is larger.
             "STOP""WAIT"? e# Select the desired output string based on this boolean.
```

So the catch is that for `UP` we invert the relative sizes of the prices, so that we can cover all cases with a single inequality at the end.

Comment: I've requested clarification from the OP and he said the code should work for several lines of input. The shortest way to achieve this should be this: `"㫅㍸ꕆ敟鸢Ꝓ約䢫솓儓隆뻨"2G#b128b:c~`

Comment: @Dennis Ugh, scoring by characters... thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 35

```
#!perl -pl
/,/;$_=$`-$'&&$`>$'^/D/?STOP:WAIT
```

Test [me](http://ideone.com/Zwmujl).

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```perl
while(<>){@p=split",";print($p[0]<$p[1]and$p[2]=~/D/?"STOP":"WAIT")."\n"}
```

Here's how it works:

- `while(<>)` parses every line.
- `@p=split","` splits it by every comma. It's using the default Perl operator, `$_` (which is where the line is stored.)
- `print (ternary)` determines what to print.
- `$p[0]<$p[1]and$p[2]=~/D/` asks if the current price is less than the price we want, and it's going down (by checking for a D.)
- `(condition)?(if):(else)` is the ternary operator.
- If our condition earlier matched, it'll output `STOP`. Otherwise, it'll output `WAIT`.

I'm assuming there is no trailing newline on the input - a trailing newline produces an extra `WAIT`.

Thanks to Alex A. for helping me save 4 bytes!

Comment: Granted it's been quite a while since I've used Perl, but does it have to be `and`? Can you use `&` or something?

Comment: @AlexA. I'm not sure why, but `&&` behaves strangely. I tried using it, and it said there was an "unmatched `<>`".

Comment: Huh. Weird. Oh well. Nice solution.

Comment: Can you do a single call to `print` and just do something like `print((condition)?"STOP":"WAIT")."\n"`?

Comment: @AlexA. Huh, did not know you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you need the parentheses around the condition? If not, that'll save another 2.

Comment: @AlexA. Apparently not, so thanks!

Comment: One more: I think you can do `say` rather than `print`,which is 2 bytes shorter, plus it implicitly appends a newline, which renders the `."\n"` and, if I'm not mistaken, the parentheses around the ternary, unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexA. It says that it doesn't know what `say` is. I have Perl v5.18.2, so is `say` only available in Perl 6+?

Comment: According to [this](http://perlmaven.com/what-is-new-in-perl-5.10--say-defined-or-state), it was new in Perl v5.10. And it's in the documentation for 5.20.1...

Comment: You changes break the code. `print($p[0]<$p[1]and$p[2]=~/D/?"STOP":"WAIT")."\n"` is equivalent to `(print(($p[0]<$p[1])and($p[2]=~/D/?"STOP":"WAIT")))."\n"` so neither the condition nor the EOL adding work as intended: http://ideone.com/dNB3xd

Comment: `say` needs to be enabled by `use v5.10` in the source or `-E` on the command line.

Comment: @nutki: I disagree with the logic grouping but I agree with the newline. [This](http://ideone.com/Aue1Gf) works as expected for me.

Comment: @AlexA., `and` and `&&` are not the same. `&&` takes precedence over `?:`, but `and` not.

Comment: Do you really need to specify p[2] in $p[2]=~/D/ ? If you omit those 4 characters and the 2 characters for =~ i'm pretty sure the match will be performed against the whole string. If the two ints are guaranteed to be decimal (as the test data always provides) then the only place a D can ever appear is in the 3rd field, so you're safe matching against the whole string. And you would have 5 fewer characters

Comment: You should also be safe replacing "\n" with the file input separator, $/ , which must contain newline or you wouldn't be able to read the file. Should save you 2 more characters.

Comment: I think you can also change while(<>){...} to map{...}<> to save 2 more characters

Answer (score 4):

## C, 85

```
c;main(i,j){for(;scanf("%d,%d,%c%*s",&i,&j,&c)>0;)puts(i-j&&i>j^c<70?"STOP":"WAIT");}
```

Test [me](http://ideone.com/eVxRXY).

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby - 89 Chars**

```
G.split.map{|a|b,c,d=a.split(?,);puts (b.to_i>=c.to_i)^(e=d[2])&&(b!=c||e)?'STOP':'WAIT'}
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/99ebf/4)

With help from to bluetorange!

Comment: Is this correct for the new equal test cases? I also tried something like this, but that failed for one of those test cases.

Comment: @Oebele didn't see that ... not sure whether they were added after my original but I've added the `=` now thanks :)

Comment: Wait - why did I myself do a complex workaround taking many bytes instead of adding `=` which I knew was also a possibility... Time to fix!

Comment: Does this account for case `1618,1618,DOWN` ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm stupid, but I don't get this code. It seems to me that for each of the 3 comma-separated values of each line, it does something with the 1st, 2nd, and 4th character and prints WAIT or STOP? Using `a.split.map{..}` prints 3 `WAIT` or `STOP` for each input line. Did you mean to do sth. like `b,c,d=a.split(?,)`? Also, `!b[3][2]` is shorter than `b[3]=='UP'`, but I think that it should be `b[2]`? Comparing strings with `>=` requires attention, as `"9">="77"` is true. The default input line separator is `\n`, so you could use `split` without arguments. `?\n` is shorter than `'\n'`.

Comment: If I change the code like this, it works for all examples correctly for me: `G.split.map{|a|b,c,d=a.split(?,);puts (b.to_i>=c.to_i)^(d[2])&&(b!=c||d[2])?'STOP':'WAIT'}`

Comment: You're right - not sure how I got away with that. I've updated it now to reflect your changes, with an added shorten on assigning `d[2]` to a variable on the first reference of it.

Comment: Glad you like it ;) Btw, your score is 90 bytes/chars, not 91. Some editors add a final newline upon saving that isn't necessary. Here's a [byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter).

Comment: I've sorted that out on the latest edit - but I'll use that byte counter in future, always learning!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>89</s> <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```python
for l in G:a,b,c=l.split(',');print('WSATIOTP'[a==b or(int(a)<int(b))^(c<'U')::2])
```

Explanation:

```python
for l in G:                                   #For every line in G:
           a,b,c=l.split(',');                #Split the line into three strings.
                              print()         #Print the contained expression.

'WSATIOTP'                                    #'WAIT' and 'STOP' interleaved.
          [                              ::2] #Select every other character.
                or                            #If either expression is true, pick 'WAIT'
           a==b
                  (             )^(     )     #Select 'WAIT' if exactly one is true.
                   int(a)<int(b)              #If first number < second number.
                                   c<'U'      #If c is 'DOWN'
```

Comment: Care to explain it?

Comment: @JuanCortés Added explanation.

Comment: Beautiful, I love it!

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>95</s> 108

R and strings, not really friends:)

```R
eval(parse(t=sub("U","<",sub("D",">",gsub("(.*),(.*),(.).*","cat(if(\\1\\3=\\2)'WAIT\n'else'STOP\n')",G)))))
```

Input is the character vector `G` then changes each string into an `if` statement that is evaluated.

**Edit** Messed up my interpretation of the rules.  Fix cost a few characters.

```R
> G=c(
+     '80,90,UP',
+     '150,100,DOWN',
+     '65,65,UP',
+     '1618,1618,DOWN',
+     '840,1200,DOWN',
+     '54,12,UP',
+     '30,1,UP'
+ )
> eval(parse(t=sub("U","<",sub("D",">",gsub("(.*),(.*),(.).*","cat(if(\\1\\3=\\2)'WAIT\n'else'STOP\n')",G)))))
WAIT
WAIT
WAIT
WAIT
STOP
STOP
STOP
>
```

Comment: Why do the last two return "wait"? They should give "stop".

Comment: @Oebele I misunderstood the rules.  It wasn't the clear for higher current prices descending.  Will fix soon

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, <s>100</s> 90 bytes

Not as small as I'd like - especially the conversion from boolean to the strings is very long. I tried to shave off a few bytes by switching to Octave, but apparently %c is not supported for textscan yet in Octave.

```
B=textscan(G,'%f,%f,%c%s\n');xor(B{1}>=B{2},B{3}==85);C(a)={'STOP'};C(~a)={'WAIT'};char(C)
```

Personally I think it is nice that this solution is the only one so far that does not use split :)

EDIT: originally solved the equals situation way too complex.

Comment: This is actually 92 bytes - you missed the ```a=``` bit before the ```xor``` function call. Though even then it doesn't actually produce the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript ECMAScript 6, 112b

```
var O="";for(let E of G.split("\n"))[A,B,C]=E.split(","),O+=("U"<C||-1)*(A-B)>0?"STOP\n":"WAIT\n";console.log(O)
```

Only on ECMAScript 6 compatible browsers

#### Explanation

```
("U"<C||-1)*(A-B)>0?"STOP\n":"WAIT\n"
```

It makes use of the fact that if we ask if 0 is true it will return false, so we can say 1 for `UP`, -1 for `DOWN`. Then we multiply that by the difference of current price and optimal price to make both of them work for the *greater than 0* part

If condition is met, return `STOP`, otherwise (including equal values) return `WAIT`

Needs further golfing

Answer (score 2):

## C- 91 Bytes

Because C has to be there somewhere

Now looks very similar to @nutki version although working out whether to output "STOP" or "WAIT" is diffferent.

Ungolfed-

```
main(i,j)
{
    char c[5];
    while(scanf("%i,%i,%s",&i,&j,c)+1)
        puts((j-i)*(*c-70)<0?"STOP":"WAIT");
}
```

Golfed-

```
 main(i,j){char c[5];while(scanf("%i,%i,%s",&i,&j,c)+1)puts((j-i)*(*c-70)<0?"STOP":"WAIT");}
```

The old one

```
Ungolfed-

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char *c="";
    while(scanf("%i,%i,%s",&i,&j,c)+1)
    {
        if(i<j)
        {
            if(*c-68)
                printf("WAIT\n");
            else
                printf("STOP\n");
        }
        if(i>j)
        {
            if(*c-68)
                printf("STOP\n");
            else
                printf("WAIT\n");
        }
        if(i==j)
            printf("WAIT\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Golfed

#define W printf("WAIT\n");
#define S printf("STOP\n");
int main(){int i,j;char *c="";while(scanf("%i,%i,%s",&i,&j,c)+1){if(i<j){if(*c-68)W else S}if(i>j){if(*c-68)S else W}if(i==j)W}return 0;}
```

I'll continue to try to cut it down

Comment: This code will just crash. You need `char c[4]` instead of `char *c=""` (which is also shorter).

Comment: @nutki , Actually, its just Undefined Behavior. A crash need not happen.

Comment: @CoolGuy, writing 5 bytes to a read only location of 1 byte. Is there a system in which this will not segfault?

Comment: @nutki - obviously my Windows PC as it worked on that!

Comment: @nutki , See? TheE's system did not throw a segfault. It is just undefined behavior. Might work on one system, but won't on the other. Anything can happen. But who cares? This is code golf so the program just needs to "work" :)  BTW, shouldn't it be `char c[5]` ( 1 space for the `\0` at the end )?

Comment: @TheE , Nice. Much shorter! +1

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (*ES6*), <strike>82</strike> <strike>80</strike> 79 bytes

*Edit: -2 using @JuanCortés multiplication method*

*Edit: -1 using a trick to reduce the multiplication method*

```js
alert(G.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.)+/g,(x,c,o,t)=>(c-o)*~{P:-2}[t]>0?'STOP':'WAIT'))
```

**Commented:**

```js
alert(                           // alert final output after replacement
    G.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.)+/g, // capture group for sections of each line
                                 // (.)+ captures only the last character
                                 // . doesn't match newlines, so this runs for each line
        (x,c,o,t)=>              // use a function to calculate each replacement string
            (c - o)              // calculate difference, negative for o>c
            *                    // multiply by
            ~{ P: -2 }[t]        // { P: -2 }[t] returns -2 for UP ('P') -2, else undefined
                                 // ~-2 => 1, ~undefined => -1
            > 0                  // if result > 0 (muplication of negatives or positives)
            ? 'STOP' : 'WAIT'    // return corresponding replacement string
    )
)
```

**Snippet Demo:**

```js
function run(){
    G = input.value;
    /* start solution */
    alert(G.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.)+/g,(x,c,o,t)=>(c-o)*~{P:-2}[t]>0?'STOP':'WAIT'))
    /* end solution */
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" cols="25" rows="7">80,90,UP
150,100,DOWN
65,65,UP
1618,1618,DOWN
840,1200,DOWN
54,12,UP
30,1,UP</textarea><br />
<button id="run" onclick="run();">Run</button>
```

**Revision History:**

```js
// 80
alert(G.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.)+/g,(x,c,o,t)=>(c-o)*(t>'N'||-1)>0?'STOP':'WAIT'))

// 82
alert(G.replace(/(.+),(.+),(.)+/g,(x,c,o,t)=>+c>o&t>'N'|+c<o&t<'P'?'STOP':'WAIT'))
```

Comment: Care to explain the logic? Looks awesome but I have no idea whats going on

Comment: @JuanCortés I've added a commented version :)

Comment: Cheers! That I do understand

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - <s>108</s> <s>106</s> <s>102</s> 97B

```
for l in G:a,b,c=l.split(',');s=int(a)-int(b);d=c<'E';print(['WAIT','STOP'][(s<0)*d+(s>0)*(1-d)])
```

Work in progress...